# Auto-generate tests for REST API

Tags: json, rest, http, testing, functional-testing

I have about 30 REST endpoints for GET, POST, PUT, DELETE. For testing their stability and functionality I would like to have tests for invalid requests:

- Empty Body (if the endpoint requires a body)
- Exisiting Body (if the endpoint requires no body)
- Invalid body data (missing values, values with wrong data types etc.)
- Invalid data for request parameters
- Invalid headers

Is their a framework where I can specify the behaviour of an endpoint (HTTP method, format of the request data, format of the response data) and which automatically generates testdata or even tests out of it?

Comment: I think this discussion on stackoverflow may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135309/automated-testing-for-rest-api