# Stability testing of REST API

Tags: rest, testing, performance-testing

I have a registration REST API which i want to test as  -

Register 15000 users and pound the server with repeated incident reports (varying traffic with max being 100 per minute, min being 1 per 24 hrs and avg being one per minute ) over a period of 48 hours.

Which tool can I use to test stability of my REST API?

Comment: Have you looked at [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)?

Comment: Search for "automated rest api testing" and you get [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135309/automated-testing-for-rest-api) and [vREST](https://vrest.io/) and more.

Comment: @KennethK. I have used jmeter but am not able to understand how could I write a test case which runs for 24 hours with varying traffic.

Answer (score 1):

For pounding the server with incidents over a period of time, you can use http://runscope.com/ .
It is helpful for testing APIs. You can just trigger events in runscope over a period time or schedule it to hit the server as required.